# JavaFX - Defining the default property

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have created a custom control that extends `Region` using the `fx:root` element. My problem is that when I try to load it, I get a `LoadException`, claiming that I need to define a `DefaultProperty`. From what I can tell, Region doesn't expose `getChildren()` as public so as to let developers decide if clients can add stuff freely or not.

My question is how do I actually define children as the default property? I tried reading the docs but they only say what the annotation is for, not how it's used. I haven't been able to find any examples either. Every time I try to annotate a field or method with `@DefaultProperty`, I just get the compile error `The annotation @DefaultProperty is disallowed for this location`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`@DefaultProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/DefaultProperty.html) annotation is a class-level annotation (`@Target(value=TYPE)` in the documentation) with a required `value` attribute specifying the name of the property.

So the following would work:

```
@DefaultProperty("children")
public class SpecialRegion extends Region {

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Node> getChildren() {
        return super.getChildren();
    }
}
```

Note that if you don't make `getChildren()` public, then the `FXMLLoader` won't be able to access it in a way that enables it to populate it. So even with the `@DefaultProperty` annotation, I don't think you can make this work without making the `getChildren()` method `public`, as above. At this point, you may as well subclass `Pane` instead of `Region`: the only differences between `Pane` and `Region` are the `public` `getChildren()` method and the `DefaultProperty`.

Comment: while this did get rid of the `LoadException`, instead I now get
`UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot determine type for property.
 at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.getSetterMethod(Unknown Source)`
when trying to add nodes to the control. I think it's because there is no setChildren method.

Comment: See update... I'm not sure there's a way to do what you want without making `getChildren()` public.

Comment: Another difference is that a Region has a Shape, you can tell it to look like a polygon. I guess I can solve this by just adding a polygon as a child of the Pane though. Anyway, your answer solved what I was originally asking for, so I'll accept it. Thanks!